# FIMSynchronizationService Error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to synchronise my user profile list with a BDC list in sharepoint 2010.

I get the following error when the BDC sync step runs.

I can't figure out how to see what is going wrong. I've tried to map my field on username, but am having no luck :(

Log Name:      Application
Source:
Date:          08/06/2011 17:00:12
Event ID:      6801
Task Category: (3)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      WIN-AIU20BM4R8U.amaze.internal
Description:
The extensible extension returned an unsupported error.
 The stack trace is:

"Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.NoSuchObjectTypeException: No such object type "user".
   at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Impl.TypeDescriptionCollectionImpl.get_Item(String Name)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ManagementAgent.ProfileImportExportExtension.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMAExtensibleFileImport.GenerateImportFile(String fileName, String connectTo, String user, String password, ConfigParameterCollection configParameters, Boolean fFullImport, TypeDescriptionCollection types, String& customData)
Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.5"
Event Xml:

  
    
    6801
    2
    3
    0x80000000000000
    
    22728
    Application
    WIN-AIU20BM4R8U.amaze.internal
    
  
  
    Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.NoSuchObjectTypeException: No such object type "user".
   at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Impl.TypeDescriptionCollectionImpl.get_Item(String Name)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ManagementAgent.ProfileImportExportExtension.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMAExtensibleFileImport.GenerateImportFile(String fileName, String connectTo, String user, String password, ConfigParameterCollection configParameters, Boolean fFullImport, TypeDescriptionCollection types, String& customData)
Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the errors in FIM are cryptic, this error means that the connected system schema does not have the user object type as expected.  This happens because there was a change to the schema in the BDC sharepoint list in-between configuring the MA and actually running it.

To fix this, refresh the schema while configuring the MA and ensure that the connected system still has the user object type.